# Trying 'match up' two disjointed datasets with common variables; macro only works for some values?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to create a macro which will 'match up' countries' past population data points to its future population data points, so I can have one data set with each country's past and future populations.

I realise vlookup may be the easiest option, but I'm trying to practise my VBA skills.

The macro that I've written below works up to a certain point, but upon reaching certain countries, will give an error 400 (or some other error). Why is this happening?

Here's the actual file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBmoRmzGQN0IDnie5UH8TDszoVQmv1C1/view?usp=sharing

```
Sub MatchUp()

Dim Past As String
Dim Future As String

For Each PastCell In Range("A1:A233")
Past = PastCell.Value

For Each FutureCell In Range("P1:P233")
    Future = FutureCell.Value

    If Past = Future Then
        Range(FutureCell.Offset(0, 1), FutureCell.Offset(0, 9)).Cut Range(PastCell.Offset(0, 15), FutureCell.Offset(0.24))
    End If

    Next FutureCell

Next PastCell          


Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a second loop, the find function would be much faster. You may need to adjust this slightly:

```
Dim Past As String, FoundCell As Range

For Each PastCell In Range("A1:A233")

Set FoundCell = Nothing
Past = PastCell.Value

Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(Past, LookAt:=xlwhole)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then Range(PastCell.Offset(0, 1), PastCell.Offset(0, 9)).Value = Range(FoundCell.Offset(0, 15), FoundCell.Offset(0.24)).Value

Next PastCell

End Sub
```